# How to Retrieve List Items from a Website

Tags: html, list, powershell, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the data from the list on the left of [this website](http://www.legal500.com/c/london-bar).

The data is structured like this :

```
<ul class="sections nice_sel">
    ...
    <li class="">
        <a href="/c/london-bar/set-overviews-england-and-wales">IMPORTANT_DATA</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Where I need to retrieve each of the `IMPORTANT_DATA` inner HTML items from the list.

I tried following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625309/use-getelementsbyclassname-in-a-script) to get the code:

```
$url = "http://www.legal500.com/c/london-bar"
$html = Invoke-WebRequest $url


$thelist = $html.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('ul') | 
    Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'sections nice_sel'}
```

But I'm not sure how to get the child (`<li>`) elements from this.

I also considered using XPath, but I can't seen to pass my `$html` variable into `-Path`:

```
Select-XML -Path $html -XPath "//*[contains(@class, 'sections nice_sel')]"
```

> Select-XML : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
>   Strict//EN" "http' does not exist.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Select-XML -Path $html -XPath "//*[contains(@class, 'Test')]"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (html ...rict//EN" "http:String) [Select-Xml], Driv 
>      eNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

---

I have also tried :

```
$url = "http://www.legal500.com/c/london-bar"
$html = Invoke-WebRequest $url

$thelist = $html.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('a') | 
    Where {$_.getAttributeNode('href').Value -contains '/c/london-bar/'}
```

But for some reason this returns nothing .. (as in `$thelist` is empty)

Comment: The parameter `-Path` specifies the path and file names of the XML files. Not the content.

Comment: @vonPryz Yes I see that now - after saving the file as `html` I tried again with the filepath, but got a `Select-XML : The file 'C:\users\Desktop\mylisthtml.html' can not be 
read: Name cannot begin with the '' character, hexadecimal value 0x0D`

Comment: Take a look: `$thelist | ForEach-Object {$_.InnerHtml ; pause}`

Comment: @JosefZ I managed to get that, but then I am left with a long string which is HTML, but it doesn't let me perform any HTML operations on it (e.g. .InnerHtml)