# PowerShell - Cannot reference attributes of elements in array returned by .getElementsByTagName()

Tags: html, powershell

I am retrieving an array of elements from a webpage via .getElementsByTagName().  I am then looping through the array and printing out the elements' titles:

```
$links = $ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
Foreach($link in $links)
{
    $link.title
}
```

This works.  However a for loop better suits my needs, and this only seems to print out blank lines:

```
$links = $ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
for($i=0; $i -lt $links.length; $i++)
{
    $links[$i].title
}
```

Why does the second loop not print the title?

Comment: I'd use PowerGui to inspect the object $links in both cases and make sure they are of the same type, and PowerShell isn't casting them somehow...

Comment: Possible confirmation, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625309/use-getelementsbyclassname-in-a-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6 methods below all print all link titles, except `Select-Object` also prints an empty line when the `title` attribute is missing:

```
$requestUri = "http://google.com"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate($requestUri)
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 }
$links = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

Write-Warning "ForEach-Object:"
$links | ForEach-Object { $_.title }

Write-Warning "Select-Object:"
$links | Select-Object title

Write-Warning "foreach:"
foreach($link in $links) { $link.title }

Write-Warning "for (from 0):"
for($i = 0; $i -lt $links.Length; $i++) {
    $links[$i].title
}

Write-Warning "for (from 1):"
for($i = 1; $i -le $links.Length; $i++) {
    $links[$i].title
}

Write-Warning "while:"
$i = 0
while($links[$i]) {
    $links[$i].title
    $i++
}

$ie.Quit()
```

Can you please try to run this on your system?

Comment: Right, I have revised my answer.

Comment: I have PowerShell v5 installed, and I guess you have v2 or v3. I'm running tests on several versions atm.

Comment: That is correct, I have v3.  v2 is even much more lacking in terms of the DOM methods it supports, I believe.

Comment: Right. So either you upgrade your version of PowerShell, or you use one of the v3-compatible methods.

Comment: Yes, the Select-Object, with a where clause, method you mentioned is actually preferable to me rather than explicitly looping through all the elements.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that `$links = $ie.document.GetElementByTagName("a")` and 
and `$links = $varDiv.GetElementsByTagName("a")` are not Equivalent in that they are not providing you with the same object type.

Comment: Whoops.  They are both pulling from a subset of elements within a div, but I meant to edit them both here as pulling from the entire document for the sake of the brevity of the question.  Edited.