# Trying to parse and interact with content from a web page using PowerShell

Tags: macos, powershell, web-scraping, powershell-core

This is what I put into PowerShell:

```
PS > $source = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=sqrt(2)"
PS > $result = Invoke-WebRequest $source
PS > $resultContainer = $result.ParsedHtml.GetElementById("results_container")
```

This is the error message I got back:

```
The property 'ParsedHtml' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.                                                                                   At line:1 char:1                                                                                                                                                             + $resultContainer = $result.ParsedHtml.GetElementById("results_contain ...                                                                                                  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Comment: I should add that I am using PowerShell in Mac's Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can do this (at least not yet) with PowerShell on non-Windows platforms. To parse the HTML content, PowerShell uses MSHTML.DLL and/or other Internet Explorer/Edge components which do not exist outside Windows. Note that GetElementById [just proxies to the COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22116066/1324345) and there's no COM objects in your environment.

You can inspect the `RawContent` property of the object returned by `Invoke-WebRequest` and parse that string yourself to look for the content you want, but parsing HTML with regular expressions is a non-starter so you'll have to use other methods.

BTW, I was unable to locate an element with an `id` of `results_container` on the page you're using in your example.

Answer (score 2):

What works (but is a bit messy) is to use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) in Powershell as .Net assembly.  It is also suggested in a [Powershell github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2867).

```
[string]$html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=viewport content=""initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"">
    <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
    <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
    <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
    <p>The requested URL <code>/error</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>";

#Loads assembly for angle sharp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257572/loading-assemblies-from-nuget-packages 
#WARNING: probably in a non-portable way.
$standardAssemblyFullPath = (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse (Split-Path (get-package AngleSharp).Source)).FullName | Where-Object {$_ -like "*standard*"}
Add-Type -Path $standardAssemblyFullPath

$parser = New-Object AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser
$document = $parser.Parse($html);

$elements = $document.All | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "logo"};

Write-Host $elements.OuterHtml
```

Comment: `HtmlParser` is a child of `Parser` namespace, not `Html` namespace. `HtmlParser` class is at `AngleSharp.Html.Parser.HtmlParser` 

`$parser = New-Object AngleSharp.Html.Parser.HtmlParser`