# Invoke-WebRequest : 'utf-8lias' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: powershell, encoding, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get get the HTML contents of the Dilbert website.
I am using the following command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://dilbert.com/" -Method Get
```

but in doing so am getting the following error message:

"Invoke-WebRequest : 'utf-8lias' is not a supported encoding name."

I tried adding ' -ContentType "text/html; charset=utf-8"' on the end but gives the same error.

How can I override the sent header encoding of 'utf-8lias' to 'utf-8'?

Thanks

Comment: What is your aim exactly? I don't know the answer precisely as for now (how to force encoding type), however I have managed to parse raw html from that site using a different method. Tell me if you are intrested

Comment: It is not you that is sending the invalid charset, but http://dilbert.com/rss that is sending `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8lias`. To get this to work you'll need to find a way to modify the response headers before processing: unlikely to be possible without – at least – making use of [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) directly yourself.  BTW it is not just you: for example https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737966

Comment: @Koliat my ultimate aim is to try and find the path to the dilbert strip image by parsing the html and then send it to print out on my littleprinter.com
Let me try what Raf suggested below first to see if that gets me any further.
Thanks

Comment: Actually what Raf posted is the way I managed to parse raw html and thus skipping the ContentType :-) I just was not sure if that would fit your needs, I don't like providing answers when I'm not sure they fit the need :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround using `System.Net.WebClient`, your html will be stored in var `$p`which will be echoed a the end:

```powershell
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$p = $webclient.DownloadString("http://dilbert.com")
$p
```

Comment: Thanks @Raf as Koliat mentioned it's now a raw html string. Is there any way to convert this into an object like Invoke-WebRequest would return so I can also access all images though something like $p.Images ?
There doesn't seem to be a cmdlet like 'ConvertFrom-HTML' or something, so I can't try something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053573/powershell-html-parsing-get-information-from-a-website either.
If it doesn't exist, would I have to try to build a Regex to find it?

Comment: Unfortunately with this workaround you only get a string. A regex would be the way to go to extract image urls but you should post that as a separate question.