# Get Google Search results via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-4.0

Let's say you only have the *artist* and *title* from a music file but you don't know the album name.

When you do a [Google search in Chrome for i.e `Golden Earring Radar Love Album`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Golden%20Earring%20Radar%20Love%20Album) you get:

[image]

You see the album name (Moontan), release date (July 1973) and even the correct album cover. How is this page section called? Google Preview? Google Instant Page? I don't know

#### My question is

How do I programmatically get these information via PowerShell?

#### What I have tried

1. [Invoke-Webrequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx): Not working, specific content not in response

   ```
   $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Golden+Earring+Radar+Love+Album"
   $Response.content | Set-Content D:\test.txt
   ```
2. [XmlHttpRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ms535874.aspx): Not working, specific content not in response

   ```
   $objXmlHttp = New-Object -ComObject MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
   $objXmlHttp.Open("GET", "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Golden+Earring+Radar+Love+Album")
   $objXmlHttp.Send()
   $objXmlHttp.responseText | Set-Content D:\test.txt
   ```
3. [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx): Not working, retrieves only URLs and their snippets

   ```
   $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Golden%20Earring%20Radar%20Love%20Album'
   $Response.responseData.results
   ```
4. I looked for a [Google Play or Google Music API](https://developers.google.com/products/) which can be used within PowerShell

I believe the problem is, that these information are loaded via Javascript which is not executed when using methods like *Invoke-WebRequest*. I could be wrong here.

I see two solutions: 1) Imitate a web browser within PowerShell and load the whole website into a form. Or 2) Use fiddler to see when and how these extra information are loaded. I would prefer the second solution but both are beyond my knowledge.

---

#### Background to avoid comments saying *There are other services like XYZ which better fit your needs*

<sup>I already have working PowerShell scripts to get album name and additional info only by a given artist and track title for numerous services including *Amazon, Deezer, Discogs, EchoNest, iTunes, Last.fm, MusicBrainz, Napster, rdio and Spotify*. Because they all offer an easy to use API (except Amazon. Their implementation is pretty hard).</sup>

<sup>I ran some tests against ~3000 music files only given the artist and track title to retrieve the according album name. And when I compared the results with Google I noticed that none of the above services were so accurate as Google was.</sup>

Comment: You're on the right track - sniffing request/responses is the key to HTTP automation. Fiddler is very easy to use - just try it. If you have basic knowledge about how HTTP works at all, you won't have any trouble interpreting its output. Otherwise start with reading an HTTP tutorial. E.g. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177

Comment: NB. Google don't *want* you to scrape their service. It means you don't see ads, don't click on sponsored links, aren't paying them any API fees, are costing them money, and might be taking the results of their hard work in an automated way - potentially to resell it/etc. It's quite possible that as you get closer to a workable fake-person using Google, it will throw CAPTCHAs at you saying "we've detected suspicious activity, please prove you're a real person".

Answer (score 6):

- open the powershell profile `ii $profile`
- paste the following snippet to the profile

```bsh
Function search-google {
        $query = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
        $args | % { $query = $query + "$_+" }
        $url = $query.Substring(0, $query.Length - 1)
        start "$url"
}

Set-Alias glg search-google
```

- restart the powershell session
- from the console just run the new command `glg hello world`
- **no quotes** for strings needed

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that Google returns different results depending on the user-agent making the request.  So in your case you're not passing a user-agent so Google assumes that it's not a browser and is limiting the amount of information that they are returning (maybe to make your parsing a little easier).

So you have a few options, two of them are:

1. As suggested by @AlexanderObersht, use Fiddler to sniff some of the network traffic and see what additional headers are being provided by default and fiddle around (pun-intended) with them to see if you can make it work.

   - With `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest` you will need to add a `-Headers` parameter
   - With XMLHttpRequest you will have to add the headers in the appropriate properties.
2. If you don't want to deal with the browser details you can just automate IE directly from Powershell.  I've got a sample shown below.

-

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application -ErrorAction Stop
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.bing.com")
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1 }

$ie.Document.DoStuff()
```

Comment: Nice answer, but maybe add a sleep: while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep 1 }

Comment: I added a header and got Invoke-WebRequest running. And your second proposed solution does work too. But both methods respond with a complete HTML site which is hard to parse. Currently I'm using some regex patterns. Not very reliable I guess. The fiddler thing was  not working. It just doesn't detect when I open a particular google URL

Comment: If you want to scrape the google results, then you'll just have to deal with the whole page.  There are many ways to parse it, but something like HTML Agility pack is probably your best bet.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053573/powershell-html-parsing-get-information-from-a-website) for some info about that.

Try running fiddler as admin.