# In Powershell, is there a way to convert html to a object with depth?

Tags: html, powershell, parsing

I was working with Powershell to experiment with webscraping and wondered if there was an easier way to deal with elements?

Is there a way to convert an Html page to an object in powershell with proper depth? Something similar to Convert-ToJson -Depth?

For example, to get a certain results:

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $URI
Write-Host $page.html.body.div[4].a[5]
```

or maybe

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $URI
$divs = $page.getElementsbyID("image-div")
$thumbs = $ $divs.getElementsbyID("thumbnails")
Write-host $thumbs[4]
```

Is there some add-on or feature already in Powershell to parse the html to an object with depth?

Comment: You can try to use [Selenium Web Browser automation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053573/powershell-html-parsing-get-information-from-a-website#9059206

Comment: The HTML Agility Pack looks promising. I'll report after testing. I have used Selenium Web Driver in PS and it works fine, but just learning and exploring alternatives in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$page.ParsedHtml` gives you the object structure.

As a tip for you to learn how to discover such functionality in `PowerShell`: Pipe your objects to `Get-Member` to see all available properties/methods, etc. And to quickly see what all the properties are, you can pipe it to `select *`

Comment: I've taken a look at Parsedhtml. 
$x = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://relatedwords.org/relatedto/winter"
$y = $x.ParsedHtml.getElementById("results-area")
$y.childNodes[7] #this gives me "words" div but cannot access the links


# what I'm trying to get is very deep parsing (like xml)

Answer (score -1):

You are likely looking for `getElementsByTagName`

```
$ret = invoke-webrequest -uri [uri]

$ret.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname('table')[0]
```

gets you the first table in your html document

```
$ret.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname('tr')[0]
```

gets you the first `<tr>` row in your HTML document.